# Bootstrap, how to avoid 2 rows to overtake the size of their containing row .?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row" style="height: 400px;background-color: red;">
  

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">

      <div class="row">
        aaaBBBB
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        CCCCC
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

which gives this result:

[image]

But I need the 2 rows (with text "aaaBBBB" and "CCCCC") to be contained in the green opaque area without the green area  to overtake the red width. I can't figure out how I can achieve this result. Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Please make an image what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example below if i got your question ?

```css
.centerAlign {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="height: 400px;background-color: red;">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 centerAlign">
       <div class="row">
        aaaBBBB
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        CCCCC
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```